# Declare array large enough to hold a type

Tags: c, arrays, embedded, size, sizeof

Suppose I'm given a function with the following signature:

```
void SendBytesAsync(unsigned char* data, T length)
```

and I need a buffer large enough to hold a byte array of the maximum length that can be specified by type `T`.  How do I declare that buffer?  I can't just use `sizeof` as it will return the size (in bytes) of type T and not the maximum value that the type could contain.  I don't want to use limits.h as the underlying type could change and my buffer be too small.  I can't use pow from math.h because I need a constant expression.  So how do I get a constant expression for the maximum size of a type at compile time in C?

### Edit

The type will be unsigned.  Since everyone seems to be appalled at the idea of a statically allocated buffer determined at compile time, I'll provide a little background.  This is for an embedded application (on a microcontroller) where reliability and speed are the priorities.  As such, I'm perfectly OK with wasting statically assigned memory for the sake of run time integrity (no `malloc` issues) and performance (no overhead for memory allocation each time I need the buffer).  I understand the risk that if the max size of `T` is too large my linker will not be able to allocate a buffer that big, but that will be a compile-time failure, which can be accommodated, rather than a run-time failure, which cannot be tolerated. If, for example I use `size_t` for the size of the payload and allocate the memory dynamically, there is a very real possibility that the system will not have that much memory available.  I would much rather know this at compile time, than at run-time where this will result in packet loss, data corruption, etc. Looking at the function signature I provided, it is ridiculous to provide a type as a size parameter for a dynamically allocated buffer and not expect the possibility that a caller will use the max value of the type.  So I'm not sure why there seems to be so much consternation about allocating that memory once, for good.  I can see this being a huge problem in the Windows world where multiple processes are fighting for the same memory resources, but in the embedded world, there's only 1 task to be done and if you can't do that effectively, then it doesn't matter how much memory you saved.

Comment: is T always signed or always unsigned?

Comment: Why is a dynamic buffer of length the value of `length` not OK?

Comment: What if `T` is `int`? Are you always going to allocate a 2 GB buffer for this purpose? What about `int64_t`? Please clarify.

Comment: The common thing to do here would be to use size_t length and let the caller tell you how long it is.  Good luck allocating the maximum of size_t (all your non-paged memory belongs to me!!!)

Comment: @JoshPetitt, it's a non-portable assumption to believe that a system has at most `SIZE_MAX` bytes of memory (think 32-bit programs running on a 64-bit OS). Unless I'm gravely mistaken, there could very well be an implementation where a program could handle multiple `SIZE_MAX` sized objects, all in memory at the same time.

Comment: @eq- True, it may be possible to do something like that (assuming that you don't run out of addressable memory).  Actually *doing* it, however, is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: @eq- Good point, bad assumption on my part.  But I did say "good luck" implying that I hope for the best to the OP when they try and do this.  I know it would fail in some situations (cause I've accidentally tried it myself).

Comment: @JoshPetitt - Thanks for your answers! The type will most assuredly be unsigned.

Comment: I added additional information to the question, addressing the comments above.

Comment: Hi Joel, per your added info.  I think the common thing would be to allocate a static buffer and choose the size.  Pass in a size_t size argument.  assert() or otherwise check that the passed size is within the bounds of your statically allocated buffer.  There is no benefit of passing anything less than a size_t to your function because it will always (AFAIK) push a native word onto your stack.  If you pass a uint8_t for example, you may incur overhead of manipulating the type.  Maybe you want the compiler to do this, or maybe it is optimized out, but maybe not.

Comment: Also, returning is size_t bytes that were sent (or added to the buffer to be sent) is a common paradigm I've seen.  But this doesn't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: Finally, I'm not appalled at allocating a static buffer that your function uses (I'm also in the embedded world).  However, limiting yourself to 2^8-1, 2^16-1, 2^32-1 is a little limiting.  For example, its probably just as easy to use a buffer of size 42.  You just make the caller continually call your function and return how many bytes your function has processed until the caller is satisfied that all their data has been processed.

Answer (score 4):

Use `_Generic`:

```
#define MAX_SIZE(X) _Generic((X),
                             long: LONG_MAX,
                             unsigned long: ULONG_MAX,
                             /* ... */)
```

Prior to C11 there isn't a portable way to find an exact maximum value of an object of type T (all calculations with `CHAR_BIT`, for example, may yield overestimates due to padding bits).

Edit: Do note that under certain conditions (think segmented memory of real-life situations) you might not be able to allocate a buffer large enough to equal the maximum value of any given type T.

Comment: @user946850, that's true. Perhaps the sized buffer is only a smokescreen for the other part of the question, that was the main point.

Answer (score 2):

if T is unsigned, then would ((T) -1) work?

(This is probably really bad, and if so, please let me know why :-) )

Comment: That's a perfectly fine (and common) method of calculating the largest value of an unsigned type, but it doesn't work for signed types.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, yeah, I asked for clarification on the question in the comments.  Doesn't seem like a signed type would make sense for the function, but one never knows...

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you are allocating the maximum possible buffer size instead of a buffer that is only as large as you need?  Why not have the caller simply specify the amount of memory needed?

Recall that the `malloc()` function takes an argument of type `size_t`.  That means that `(size_t)(-1)` (which is `SIZE_MAX` in C99 and later) will represent the largest value that can be passed to `malloc`.  If you are using `malloc` as your allocator, then this will be your absolute upper limit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using a bit shift?

let's see:

`unsigned long max_size = (1 << (8 * sizeof(T))) - 1`

sizeof(T) gives you the number of bytes T occupies in memory. (not technically true. usually the compiler will align the structure with memory... so if T is one byte, it will actually allocate 4, or something.)

Breaking it down:

`8 * sizeof(T)` gives you the number of bits that size represents

`1 << x` is the same as saying `2 to the x power`. Because every time you shift to the left, you're multiplying by two. Just as every time you shift to the left in base 10, you are multiplying by 10.

`- 1` an 8-bit number can hold 256 values. 0..255.

Comment: `(1 << (8 * sizeof(T)))` the left operand (`1`) of the `<<` operator is of type `int` here and can overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I would start by looking in the 'limits' header for the max value of a numeric type T. I have not tried it but I would do something that uses T::max

Comment: OP is asking about C, not C++.  There's nothing like `T::max` in C (were you thinking of C++'s `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`?)

Comment: well he did say 'T' - made me think he was referring to c++